# Create multiple directories with -p option

Tags: command-line, mkdir

Why does this command

```
sudo mkdir -p \
  /opt/nginx/conf.d \
  /opt/gitlab/config
```

throw the error `/opt/gitlab/config: File or directory not found`. I'm expecting to create it. Also I used the `-p` flag.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /opt/gitlab /opt/gitlab/config` ? If one or both of them already exist and are something other than a directory, that could explain what you see.

Comment: `opt` is existing; `/opt/gitlab` is not existing

Comment: I don't see that message in the GNU coreutils `mkdir`; which one are you using? `mkdir --version`; and which OS?

Comment: 8.25 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: could you try with `-v` (verbose)  and post the output?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a non-printing character in the gitlab path?

Comment: Could you have possibly missed the very last backslash, to where the script tried to *execute* (the non-existent) /opt/gitlab/config?